Lower Bound on the ratio of binomial coefficients
Let $k,n,m$ be integers such that $k>n>m$. I am interested in providing a tight lowerbound on
$$
A(k,n,m)=\frac{\binom{k-m}{n-m}}{\binom{k}{n}}
$$
This term arises in a probability problem that is related to the sampling without replacement. Using simple techniques I proved
$$
A(k,n,m) \geq \exp\left(-(k-n)\cdot \frac{m}{n-m+1}\right).
$$
I am looking for a cleaner and tighter lowerbound.

It is well known that $$\binom{k}{n}\binom{n}{m}=\binom{k}{m}\binom{k-m}{n-m}. \tag1\label1$$
For a combinatorial proof, consider $A \subseteq B \subseteq [k]$ with $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$.
Rewriting \eqref{1} yields
$$\frac{\binom{k-m}{n-m}}{\binom{k}{n}}=\frac{\binom{n}{m}}{\binom{k}{m}},$$
which is a simpler and exact lower bound.
If you prefer, you can rewrite as
$$\frac{n!(k-m)!}{k!(n-m)!}.$$
To obtain a lower bound without factorials, use Robbins' bounds
$$\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\exp\left(\frac{1}{12n+1}\right) < n! < \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\exp\left(\frac{1}{12n}\right),$$
yielding
$$\frac{n!(k-m)!}{k!(n-m)!}
>
\frac{n^{n+1/2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{12n+1}\right)(k-m)^{k-m+1/2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{12(k-m)+1}\right)}{ k^{k+1/2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{12k}\right)(n-m)^{n-m+1/2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{12(n-m)}\right)}. \tag2\label2$$
For the $A(12,6,3)$ example in the answer by @ClaudeLeibovici, the lower bound \eqref{2} turns out to be
$$\frac{19683 \sqrt{3}}{262144 \sqrt{2} e^{13577/1145808}} \approx 0.090876.$$

The lowerbound in the question is exactly based on manipulating the term in your answer. I am looking for a lowerbound without factorial.

$$A(k,n,m)=\frac{\binom{k-m}{n-m}}{\binom{k}{n}}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)\,\, \Gamma(k-m+1)}{\Gamma (k+1)\,\, \Gamma(n-m+1)}$$ Let
$n=a k$ and $m=b k$ (with $1>a>b$ and, as usual, take logarithms and use Stirling approximation to get
$$\log\big(A(k,n,m)  \big)=\alpha\, k +\beta +\frac \gamma k+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\tag 1$$ with
$$\alpha=a \log (a)+(1-b) \log(1-b)-(a-b) \log (a-b) $$
$$\beta=\frac{1}{2} (\log (a)+\log (1-b)-\log (a-b))$$
$$\gamma=-\frac{(1-a) b (a-b+1)}{12 a (1-b) (a-b)}$$
For a try: $k=12$, $n=6$, $m=3$ gives
$$\log\big(A(12,6,3)  \big)\sim -\frac 5{432}+\frac{1}{2} (19 \log (3)-37 \log (2))$$
$$A(12,6,3)\sim \frac{19683 \sqrt{3}}{262144 \sqrt{2}  e^{5/432}}=0.0909014$$ while the exact value is $\frac 1{11}=0.0909091$.
Edit (after @RobPratt's comment)
If we take the next term of the expansion which is $O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$, it write
$$\delta =\frac {B}{360 a^3 (1-b)^3 (a-b)^3}$$ and
$$B=(1-a)b(1+a-b) C$$
Let $b=c\,a$ (with $c<1$) and then
$$C=a^2\,D$$ with
$$D=(1-c)^2 c^2\,a^4-(1-c)c \left(c^2-3 c+3\right)\,a^3+$$ $$\left(c^2-3 c+3\right)\left(c^2-c+1\right)\, a^2-2 c \left(c^2-3 c+3\right)\,a+\left(c^2-3 c+3\right)$$
The minimum value of $D$ is equal to $0$ for $a=c=1$ (its maximum value is $6$ for $a=1$ and $c=0)).
So $D>0$ implies $\delta >0$ and,as written, $(1)$ is a lower bound.

This is an approximation but not quite a lower bound.

@RobPratt. I did not claim it. I shall continue then. Cheers :-)

I mentioned it because the OP asked for a lower bound.

@RobPratt. Thanks for pushing me ! Have a look at my edit.
